# jQuery Quiz compare correct answer in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

**My HTML**

```
<div class="questions">
    <p>Q1</p>
    <label><input name="q1" id="q1-a" type="radio" />Q1 ans A</label>
    <label><input name="q1" id="q1-b" type="radio" />Q1 ans B</label>
    <label><input name="q1" id="q1-c" type="radio" />Q1 ans C</label>
</div>

<div class="questions hide">
    <p>Q2</p>
    <label><input name="q2" id="q1-a" type="radio" />Q2 ans A</label>
    <label><input name="q2" id="q1-b" type="radio" />Q2 ans B</label>
    <label><input name="q2" id="q1-c" type="radio" />Q2 ans C</label>
</div>

<div class="questions hide">
    <p>Q3</p>
    <label><input name="q3" id="q1-a" type="radio" />Q3 ans A</label>
    <label><input name="q3" id="q1-b" type="radio" />Q3 ans B</label>
    <label><input name="q3" id="q1-c" type="radio" />Q3 ans C</label>
</div>
<a href="#" id="checkAns">Check</a>
```

**MY JS**

```
$("#checkAns").click(function(){

}
```

Here are the array of answer which I want to compare

```
answers: { q1: 'a', q2: 'b', q3: 'a'}
```

If user trigger radio button then it will show alert if is Correct or Wrong then it will return true; if wrong false then this is the time it will show another question for answering

I do want to avoid if else in checking the user answer is this possible?

Comment: I would be more careful when I copy-paste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, don't forget to add value on each radio button. Also `id` is not really needed here, except you need to do something on each radio button:

```
<div>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="a" />Q1 A</label>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="b" />Q1 B</label>
    <label><input name="q1" type="radio" value="c" />Q1 C</label>
</div>
```

Then for checking answers, you can use this:

```
var answers = {q1 : 'a', q2 : 'b', q3 : 'a'};

$('#checkAns').click(function(e) {
    $.each(answers, function(question, answer) {
        if($('input:radio[name="' + question + '"]:checked').val() == answer)
            alert(question + ': True');
        else
            alert(question + ': False!');
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

**Updated answer :**

HTML & CSS

I think you don't need an anchor to click, because this time the script check the answer as soon as the radio button is triggered.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hide { display:none; }
</style>

<div class="questions">
    <p>Q1</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" />Q1 A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" />Q1 B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" />Q1 C</label>
</div>

<div class="questions hide">
    <p>Q2</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="a" />Q2 A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="b" />Q2 B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="c" />Q2 C</label>
</div>

<div class="questions hide">
    <p>Q3</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="a" />Q3 A</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="b" />Q3 B</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="c" />Q3 C</label>
</div>
```

Javascript using jQuery

```
var answers = {q1: 'a', q2: 'b', q3: 'a'};

$('input:radio').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).parents('div');
    var question = $(this).attr('name');
    var answer = $(this).val();

    alert(answers[question] == answer);

    container.addClass('hide');
    container.next().removeClass('hide');
});
```

Just modify the script as you need. Hope this time is right.. :P

Comment: @o q Thanks Buddy but it do loads all the alert's what I want it to do is to load alert of each answer every radio button trigger by the user

Comment: Ah, it's my bad not to read your question carefully. I already add updated answer..